# Databinding to class member functions

Tags: angular, typescript

Assume I have to following classes:

```
export class Address {
    id: number;
    streetAndNumber: string;
    addressSuffix: string;
    city: string;
    zip: string;

    toString(): string {
        return this.streetAndNumber + ', ' + this.zip + this.city;
    }

    asOptionX(): string {
        return 'asjfhklasjfh';
    }
}

export class Person {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    address: Address;
}
```

An Object of type Person is retrieved by HttpClient:

```
this.http.get<Person>(...).subscribe(data => person = data;)
```

Now I like to have a databinding in my template e.g.:

```
<div>{{person.address}}</div>
```

Why does this output `[Object object]`? It seems that toString() is not available.

If I try:

```
<div>{{person.address.asOptionX()}}</div>
```

An error is output in console: `...address.asOptionX is not a function`.

I also have no luck trying to make getters and bind to them.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make an HTTP call, the answer you're getting is a plain Object, not an instance of a class.

In code, this would mean that you make

```
const person = { address: {...}, id: 1, description: '' };
```

Instead of

```
const person = new Person(1, '', new Address(...));
```

You need to explicitly state that your object is an instance of a class.

To do that, you will need to map your call like this

```
this.http.get<Person>(...)
  .map(person => {
    const _person = new Person();
    _person.id = person.id;
    // ... And so on
  });
```

You could either use this, or a custom constructor, or a function that takes your response and returns an instance. Some libraries exist too, that can do that, such as [class transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're not mapping the object to the class - you're saying it has that *type*, but that's not the same as creating an instance of a `Person` and then creating an instance of an `Address` within it.

You need to create a constructor for `Person` and take the correct member data from `data`, and do the same for the `Address` - but call that constructor from within the `Person` constructor.

A **very** bad way (that works) is to simply have the constructor similar to this -

```
export class Address {
    constructor(data: object) {
        super();
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    ...
}
```

You should however just copy the correct members over - doesn't take much more work, and is a lot safer...

Comment: Why is there a super call ? Otherwise, could you explain why it is bad ? I kind of like the simplicity (I didn't know this way before)

Comment: In a constructor you should always include the `super()` call to pass any init up higher in the chain (in this case for the Object constructor). It's bad because you could be overriding things this way and aren't checking that it's actually correct data - ie, validating that there's not a typo etc - it also makes it harder to test because you're basically allowing anything through. Finally this way doesn't work for making a subclass - you'd still need `Person` to have a `this.address = new Address(data.address);` for that.